# Why I cannot access dynamic allocated memory in my for loop?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I new a memory for my child class type stock which is inherited from base class instrument, when I try to access the second element of my array, it throws error. Things are fine when I my new array size is 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Instrument{

public:
    virtual void display(){}
    virtual void output(){}
    virtual void readFile(){}
    virtual ~Instrument(){}
};
class Stock : 
    public Instrument{
public:
    Stock(){

    }
    virtual void input(){
        cout << "This is stock, please input its information: ";
        cin >> name >> bidPrice >> askPrice >> lastPrice >> issueExchange;
    }
    virtual void display(){
        cout <<"This is to display stock: "<< name << " "
            << bidPrice << " "
            << askPrice << " "
            << lastPrice << " "
            << issueExchange << " "
            << endl;
    }
    virtual void output(){
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("Stock.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
        if (myfile.is_open()){
            myfile << "This is a stock: "
                << name << " "
                << bidPrice << " "
                << askPrice << " "
                << lastPrice << " "
                << issueExchange << " "
                << endl;
        }
        else cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
    virtual void readFile(){
        string line;
        ifstream myfile("Stock.txt");
        cout << "\nThis is file stored\n";
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(myfile, line))
            {
                cout << line << '\n';
            }
            myfile.close();
        }
    }
    virtual ~Stock(){}
private:
    char name[13];
    double bidPrice;
    double askPrice;
    double lastPrice;
    int issueExchange;

};


int main(){

    const int N = 5;//it works fine if I use N=1;
    Instrument *pBase = NULL;
    pBase = new Stock[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        pBase[i].input();// here throws an exception and ends the program
        pBase[i].display();
        pBase[i].output();
    }
    pBase[N - 1].readFile();
    delete[] pBase;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @GermaineJason This isn´t Java or C#. There are objects, and a NPE does not exist.

Comment: Interesting, I see the error, and am quite surprised that I've never seen this before.  It's almost like slicing, but it's different.  @GermaineJason There are 5 objects in the array.

Comment: @MooingDuck, it is changed from string to char[13], do you see my #include<string>

Comment: Huh this is so obvious yet I've never thought of it. Interesting!

Comment: The problem is you are accessing a `Stock` array as if it were an `Instrument` array.  Polymorphism doesn't work between whole arrays, you need a pointer to each individual element.

Comment: @Galik: Please do not answer questions in the comment section. That is what the _answer_ section is for. Thank you.

Comment: @deviantfan: Yeah he was wrong

Answer (score 7):

Polymorphism and pointer arithmetic do not mix, because the arrangement of objects within an array depends on the most-derived size, and polymorphism loses that information.  The dynamic allocation is a red herring, you can see the same problem with:

```
Derived array[2];
Base* p = array;

printf("%p\n", &array[0]);
printf("%p\n", p);
printf("%p\n", &array[1]);
printf("%p\n", p + 1);

printf("%z\n", sizeof (array[0]));
printf("%z\n", sizeof (*p));
```

Note that the pointer values using `array` are moving forward by `sizeof (Derived)`, but pointer arithmetic using `p` is moving forward by `sizeof (Base)` and not finding the real objects.

Generally you would fix this using an array of `Base*`, instead of a single `Base*` combined with pointer arithmetic.

```
Base* pp[2];
for( auto& elem : array ) pp[&elem - array] = &elem;

printf("%p\n", &array[1]);
printf("%p\n", pp[1]);

// use (*pp[1]) or pp[1]->whatever
```

Another option is to use an object that remembers the original type:

```
Derived* allocated = new Derived[N];
std::function<Base& (int)> poly = [allocated](int i){ return allocated[i]; };
```

and use `poly(i)` instead of `p[i]`

But warning, you CANNOT do `delete [] &poly(0);` because `delete[]` is not polymorphic either.

Using `std::unique_ptr<Derived[]>` and `std::bind`, one could arrange for automatic deallocation when the accessor object finally goes out of scope.

Comment: While accurate, this answer is a bit lacking in the explanation, isn't it?

Comment: yes, that the point, but my assignment asks me to use polymorphism and array in the same time, I try to use intrument *p[N], and access p[i], but it does not work here. This is the new way I tried

Comment: @Leewis You could use eg. an array of pointers (whatever kind) to single objects, instead of an array of objects itself.

Comment: Yeah I see that pattern a lot in beginner code on SO. I don't like it though. `n` times `new` and, like, no memory locality :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You can also use an array of pointers, each to the corresponding element within an array.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is there a better solution (than pointers to anywhere) if the assignment asks directly to use a polymorphic array? (Well, aside from a typeID() method or anything in this direction. Don´t think it will make anything better)

Comment: @Marius: Thanks, I keep mixing up the C++11 and C++/CLI syntax

Answer (score 0):

Although Mr.Ben's method is absolutely right, but I totally feel that his C++ and my C++ are not the same language, his is mixing some strange things here, thus according to his idea, I tried to modify my code like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Instrument{

public:
    virtual void display() = 0;
    virtual void output() = 0;
    virtual void readFile() = 0;
    virtual ~Instrument(){};
};
class Stock :
    public Instrument{
public:
    Stock(){
        cout << "This is stock, please input its information: ";
        cin >> name >> bidPrice >> askPrice >> lastPrice >> issueExchange;
    }
    virtual void display(){
        cout << "This is to display stock: " << name << " "
            << bidPrice << " "
            << askPrice << " "
            << lastPrice << " "
            << issueExchange << " "
            << endl;
    }
    virtual void output(){
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("Stock.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
        if (myfile.is_open()){
            myfile << "This is a stock: "
                << name << " "
                << bidPrice << " "
                << askPrice << " "
                << lastPrice << " "
                << issueExchange << " "
                << endl;
        }
        else cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
    virtual void readFile(){
        string line;
        ifstream myfile("Stock.txt");
        cout << "\nThis is file stored\n";
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(myfile, line))
            {
                cout << line << '\n';
            }
            myfile.close();
        }
    }
    virtual ~Stock(){}
private:
    string name;
    double bidPrice;
    double askPrice;
    double lastPrice;
    int issueExchange;

};
class Option :
    public Instrument{
public:
    Option(){
        cout << "This is option, please input its information: ";
        cin >> name >> uname >> bidPrice >> askPrice >> lastPrice >> contractSize >> exp;
    }
    virtual void display(){
        cout << "This is to display option: "
            << name << " "
            << uname << " "
            << bidPrice << " "
            << askPrice << " "
            << lastPrice << " "
            << contractSize << " "
            << exp << " "
            << endl;
    }
    virtual void output(){
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("Option.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
        if (myfile.is_open()){
            myfile << "This is an option: "
                << name << " "
                << uname << " "
                << bidPrice << " "
                << askPrice << " "
                << lastPrice << " "
                << contractSize << " "
                << exp << " "
                << endl;
        }
        else cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
    virtual void readFile(){
        string line;
        ifstream myfile("Option.txt");
        cout << "\nThis is file stored\n";
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(myfile, line))
            {
                cout << line << '\n';
            }
            myfile.close();
        }
    }
    virtual ~Option(){}
private:
    string name;
    string uname;
    double bidPrice;
    double askPrice;
    double lastPrice;
    int contractSize;
    double exp;
};
class Future :
    public Instrument{
public:
    Future(){
        cout << "This is option, please input its information: ";
        cin >> name >> uname >> bidPrice >> askPrice >> lastPrice >> contractSize >> tickSize >> contractMonth;
    }
    virtual void display(){
        cout << "This is to display option: "
            << name << " "
            << uname << " "
            << bidPrice << " "
            << askPrice << " "
            << lastPrice << " "
            << contractSize << " "
            << tickSize << " "
            << contractMonth << " "
            << endl;
    }
    virtual void output(){
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("Future.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
        if (myfile.is_open()){
            myfile << "This is a future: "
                << name << " "
                << uname << " "
                << bidPrice << " "
                << askPrice << " "
                << lastPrice << " "
                << contractSize << " "
                << tickSize << " "
                << contractMonth << " "
                << endl;
        }
        else cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
    virtual void readFile(){
        string line;
        ifstream myfile("Future.txt");
        cout << "\nThis is file stored\n";
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(myfile, line))
            {
                cout << line << '\n';
            }
            myfile.close();
        }
    }
    virtual ~Future(){}
private:
    string name;
    string uname;
    double bidPrice;
    double askPrice;
    double lastPrice;
    int contractSize;
    int tickSize;
    int contractMonth;
};

int main(){

    int N = 20;
    //shared_ptr<Instrument> pBase[N];
    vector<shared_ptr<Instrument>> pBase(N);
    int i = 5;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) pBase[i] = make_shared<Stock>();
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        pBase[i]->display();
        pBase[i]->output();
    }
    pBase[N - 1]->readFile();

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) pBase[i] = make_shared<Option>();
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        pBase[i]->display();
        pBase[i]->output();
    }
    pBase[N - 1]->readFile();

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) pBase[i] = make_shared<Future>();
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        pBase[i]->display();
        pBase[i]->output();
    }
    pBase[N - 1]->readFile();

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr answer: don't convert subclass array (`Stock[N]`) to a base class pointer (`pBase`). Either directly use `Stock*`, or create an array of pointers instead:

```
auto arr = new Stock*[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  arr[i] = new Stock();
}

// unrelated but suggested: C++11 unique_ptr is recommended:
vector<unique_ptr<Stock>> v(N);
```

Detailed reasons:

1) Array bracket operator is a syntactic sugar: `a[b] -> *(a + b)`;

2) Pointer arithmetic is not polymorphic, it's always based on static types:

```
pBase[i] -> *(pBase+i) -> *(pBase*)((char*)pBase + sizeof(Instrument) * i);
```

3) This is, however, what you want:

```
pBase[i] -> *(pBase+i) -> *(pBase*)((char*)pBase + sizeof(Stock) * i);
```

4) As long as `sizeof(Instrument) != sizeof(Stock)`, you are in trouble.

Comment: I do, see my answer, vector<shared_ptr<Instrument>> pBase(N);